# when uploading videos to tiktok/youtube, as oringal content creators what copyright do we transfer to the platform, what is left to the creators?

Tags: united-states, ownership, data-ownership, copyright-transfer

when uploading videos to tiktok/youtube, as original content creators what copyright do we transfer to the platform, what is left to the creators?

where can we learn more those "laws" on their platforms?  Do we have any laws that transfer ownership completely, meaning that as soon as we use the platforms to upload content we agree to transfer the owner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when uploading videos to tiktok/youtube, as original content creators what copyright do we transfer to the platform, what is left to the creators?

Most of these platforms provide that the creator retains all copyright but grants the platform a non-exclusive and irrevocable license to redistribute and reuse the content.

> Where can we learn more those "laws" on their platforms?

They are found in the terms of service.

> Do we have any laws that transfer ownership completely, meaning that as soon as we use the platforms to upload content we agree to transfer the owner?

Most platforms avoid this, probably because they do not want to alienate potential users.  Most people would not upload their videos or other creations to a platform that would sue them for making subsequent use of the uploaded material.

For example, from [YouTube's terms of service](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms):

> Rights you Grant
>
> You retain all of your ownership rights in your Content. In short, what belongs to you stays yours. However, we do require you to grant certain rights to YouTube and other users of the Service, as described below.
>
> Licence to YouTube
>
> By providing Content to the Service, you grant to YouTube a worldwide, non-exclusive, royalty-free, transferable, sublicensable licence to use that Content (including to reproduce, distribute, modify, display and perform it) for the purpose of operating, promoting, and improving the Service.
>
> Licence to Other Users
>
> You also grant each other user of the Service a worldwide, non-exclusive, royalty-free licence to access your Content through the Service, and to use that Content (including to reproduce, distribute, modify, display, and perform it) only as enabled by a feature of the Service.
>
> Duration of Licence
>
> The licences granted by you continue until the Content is removed as described below. Once removed, the licences will terminate, except where the operation of the Service, use of Content permitted before your removal, or the law requires otherwise.  For example, removal of Content by you does not require YouTube to: (a) recall Content that is being used by other users within any limited offline viewing functionality of the Service; or (b) delete copies we reasonably need to keep for legal purposes.

Comment: "grants the platform a non-exclusive and irrevocable license to redistribute and reuse the content." seem to me, the platform and the original creator both have the same rights.

Comment: @Maxfield Not quite. In the YouTube example, for example, notice that you are not giving YouTube a right to redistribute or reuse your content outside of their platform (the "Service"). As the owner, you're obviously allowed to do that (e.g. to post it on YouTube as well as on some other platform/service as well). If you look at other Terms's of Service (ToS's), I think you will find a similar pattern (normally, in the Terms, you're only granting a right for that platform to use your content on that same service itself).

Comment: @Maxfield trivially, "moral rights" are not transferable, so the platform does not have the right to claim that it created the content (but it also would not have that right even if the user did transfer all transferable rights rather than licensing them). As Brandin points out, there are other rights that the platform does not necessarily obtain, though these will depend on the specific terms of service. In YouTube's case, they only have the right to use the content to operate, promote, or improve their service.

Comment: @Brandin YouTube can use user content outside of YouTube for the purpose of promoting YouTube (or operating or improving it), for example in a television advertisement (at least, that's what the terms of service purport to provide).